# Split record into 2 records with distinct values based on a unique id

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with some IDs that correspond to duplicate data that i would like to get rid of.  They are linked by a groupid number.  Currently my data looks like this:

```
|GroupID|NID1  |NID2  |
|S1     |644763|643257|
|T2     |4759  |84689 |
|W3     |96676 |585876|
```

In order for the software to run, I need the data in the following format:

```
|GroupID|NID   |
|S1     |644763|
|S1     |643257|
|T2     |4759  |
|T2     |84689 |
|W3     |96676 |
|W3     |585876|
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `union all` :

```
select groupid, nid1 as nid
from table t
union all -- use "union" instead if you don't want duplicate rows
select groupid, nid2
from table t;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked perfectly (unlike my head this morning). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12C+, you can use lateral joins:

```
select t.groupid, v.nid
from t cross apply
     (select t.nid1 as nid from dual union all
      select t.nid2 as nid from dual
     ) v;
```

This is more efficient than `union all` because it only scans the table once.

You can also express this as:

```
select t.groupid,
       (case when n.n = 1 then t.nid1 when n.n = 2 then t.nid2 end) as nid
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n;
```

A little more complicated, but still only one scan of the table.